# Advice on approach to accessing MYSQL database from mobile app

Tags: mysql, rest, codenameone

Quick bit of advice if i may. I'm a startup company and developing a new mobile app that i intend to query and update data from a cloud MYSQL database, using a restful webservice and JSON. I am pretty new to this, but ok on the theory.

I originally thought i could use Dropbox to host the database and somehow install a Tomcat server also, to act as the http server, but i cant find anything online that says this is achievable. I've now found a temporary site heliohost.org, which offers free hosting, so i'm looking into that.

Does anyone have advice on a [low cost] longer term production cloud service for MYSQL database? And am i right that a good approach is to create a restful webservice in Eclipse and then somehow deploy that to the Tomcat server in the cloud, so that my app can then issue calls to it via the CN1 available methods.

There is quite a lot out there and much of it is self-promoting their own sites so was after some independent advice please.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question as it is now here is off-topic: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't host and access an SQL server over the network from a device as access is remarkably unreliable and insecure. You will need some form of hosting. I used [Linode](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-from-digital-ocean-linode.html) for our [online course](http://codenameone.teachable.com/) since they are very affordable (5USD per month) but I've used AWS, Digital Ocean and others. They are all good.

You are correct that you will need to create a webservice, I used tomcat in the past but for the latest course I chose SpingBoot which is easier and more modern.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Linode looks both robust and affordable, although they claim the database needs higher than the basic package, so that may affect things. You mention 'hosting and accessing' over the network. My approach is to host MYSQL and Tomcat on something like Linode and access it from the device via a restful webservice. I don't think this comes under the 'unreliable and insecure' banner, thought, frankly, is my first time.

Comment: That's the right way to do that. I was referring to exposing the mysql connection over the network

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this post, i spent a couple of hours and got Linode up and running ($5/mo) with mysql and Tomcat (with locally installed SQLDeveloper tunneling to the database). Then another couple of hours of following the post below and i have a working restful webservice, query my database, testing through Postman.   https://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html

Answer (score 2):

Using a mobile backend to store and retrieve data is a vast topic to discuss where different tools and services can be leveraged based on your application use cases.

However directly accessing MySQL server from your mobile client wouldn't be a recommended approach both in term of security as well as performance at scale.

Few options you can consider.

- Developing the mobile backend with [Amazon Mobile Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/products/frontend-web-mobile/) where you can find different architectures and services. For example.
- Using AWS DynamoDB as a Mobile Backend tightly controlling access permissions with AWS Cognito and DynamoDB Fine Grained Access Control.
- Using Cognito Sync as a storage medium to Synchronize data from Mobile App to AWS and then using triggers to share and push data & etc.
- Developing a REST API for the mobile backend using AWS Services such as API Gateway, Lambda & DynamoDB(Or Relational Databases like MySQL, Postgres SQL & etc. with RDS)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.